# Layout components, such as flexbox, navbar, etc

Tags: layout, flexbox, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm very new to KendoUI. I browsed through the repository of components for KendoUI for Angular 2. Now I'm wondering whether layout components such as navbar with menu, flexbox (or something similar) and other kind of containers will follow in the final. Or how to achieve responsive design, despite the few action components (button, multi-select, ...).

Maybe, I still need to use regular bootstrap and suchlike do design my web application.

Answer (score 1):

even though the reply is kind of late.

Indeed, the set of components offered by Telerik (and others too), are not yet complete.

You can find balance between Telerik's suite and bootstrap for angular 2, and even other components, depending on your requirements.

In our case, we used Telerik Grid, and chart, and https://bmorton.co.uk/angular/ and other bootstrap components.

Regards,
O.D.